# Android grid view with inside borders

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-calendar

I am trying to make a calendar app, and I want every cell inside to be with a border, like its a table, but I can't figure out how to do it, this is the adapter that populates the grid view

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
    }
    v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) Math.ceil((parent.getWidth() / 7)), (int) Math.ceil((parent.getWidth() / 7))));
    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    dayView.setText(days[position].toString());
    dayView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    dayView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    if (days[position].getMonth() - 1 != month.get(Calendar.MONTH) || days[position].getYear() != month.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(154, 154, 154));
    } else {
        if (days[position].hasEvent()) {
            if (days[position].getIsSelected()) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        } else {
            if (days[position].getIsSelected()) {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

and this is calendar_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how it looks like now
[image]

Comment: Try to set custom border image with transparent area to grid item parent layout.

Comment: create custom shape, set as background of layout ( calendar_item.xml )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a file `.xml` in your `drawable folder` with the name "shape_my_border.xml" with the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<!-- Change to the color you want for the background -->
<solid android:color="@color/white" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/grey_border" />
    <!-- Change to the color you want for the border -->
</shape>
```

Then, use this as the `background` of your `LinearLayout` like `android:background="@drawable/shape_my_border"`.

If you want to change the background or the border as you click on a day of your calendar, you have to create a `selector` file the same way you created the "shape_my_border.xml" file but you have to use a code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_border_2" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!-- selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_border_2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_border_2" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_border_1"/>
<!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shape as bg of the cell item (in your case the LinearLayout) :)

Here an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
     <gradient android:startColor="#DD000000" android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA" 
            android:angle="225"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

And remove the bg from the textview to see the result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: where do I make this xml in? Tried in drawable, then used it as a background for calendar_item.xml but nothing happens

Comment: Have you removed the tv bg?